# how to get php response by using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

In a html web page, i want PHP response show in `<span>..</span>`.
Can anyone tell me how to do it or what's wrong with other codes?
thanks~~ ^^
web code:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">    
       $("#submit").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
               type: 'get',
               url: 'php/test.php',
               dataType:'json',
               success: function(data) { 
                  //dosomething.....
               },
           });
       });
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form method="post">
           <input id="submit" type="button" value="next">
       </form>
       <br><br><span id ="status"></span>
   </body>
</html>
```

php code:

```
<?php
echo ("success");
?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the two files, the file where you request the php page and the file where you will send the response.

Comment: you expect json but you print text. Either change dataType to text or in php use json_encode

Answer (score 0):

After you get the response do the following

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
               type: 'get',
               url: 'php/test.php',
               dataType:'json',
               success: function(data) { 
                  $("span#status").html(data);
               },
           });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as the datatype provided won't be JSON... the **dataType** attribute in jQuery must match the type of data you send using PHP.

To get it working with a simple "success" message, you may do :

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
       type: 'get',
       url: 'php/test.php',
       dataType:'html',
       success: function(data) { 
          $("span#status").html(data);
       },
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `dataType: "json"`, the AJAX function thinks it's getting a JSON array. But since you only respond with "succes" in your php, it will not parse as JSON.

You should JSONify your output in PHP with `json_encode()`, after that you can call the `succes` callback in ajax, or use the `.done` function;

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'php/test.php',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) { 
            $("span#status").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

or with **.done** functionality:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'php/test.php',
        dataType:'json',
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("span#status").html(data);
    });
});
```

The .done function is better for readability and maintainability in my opinion.